# Using free() makes string returned by strtok to be empty

Tags: c, string, memory-management, strtok

I have the following method

```
void set_actions(char *input, char **actions)
{
   int index = 0;
   char *str = (char*)malloc(strlen(input));
   strcpy(str,input);
   char *tok = NULL;
   tok = strtok(str," ");

   while(tok!=NULL)
   {
     actions[index]=tok;
     tok=strtok(NULL," ");
     index++;
   }

   free(str);
}
```

after calling this method in main like:

```
char *input ="A B C";
char *actions[3];
set_actions(input, actions);
```

The result is:

```
actions[0] = is empty
actions[1] = is empty
actions[2] = C
```

if I delete the "free(str)" 
then

```
actions[0] = A
actions[1] = B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the manual for `strtok` and figure out what its return values mean.

Comment: In addition to Kerrek's point, you also need to allocate space for the null terminator - `char *str = malloc(strlen(input)+1);`

Comment: Do not refer to the area after release.

Comment: And remeber don't access memory after you free() them, anything can happen, and you shouldn't do this. Do free() only when you are sure they will no longer being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
actions[index]=strdup(tok);
```

instead of

```
actions[index]=tok;
```

In fact `tok` is a pointer pointing to an address into the array `str`. When you free `str`, the `tok` become pointed to an address address that already freed. So you have to keep a copy of the tok content in another memory address. `strdup` allow to allocate memory and then copy the tok content in this memory

and then when your `action[]` array become useless in your code do not forget to free each elemet in the array

```
for (i=0;i<max;i++)
    free(actions[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand why. After doing some changes according to you explanations it's working!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` modifies the string in place. So the substrings that it returns are in fact segments of the buffer that you allocated for `str`, they are not in separate memory regions.

In C, a string runs until the next null byte (byte value 0). The way `strtok` works is that it replaces the string separator character by a null byte in place. So where you have before

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'A' | '␣' | 'B' | '␣' | 'C' |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
^
str
```

(where `'␣'` is a space character), then after calling `strtok`, you have

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'A' |  0  | 'B' |  0  | 'C' |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
^           ^           ^
actions[0]  actions[1]  actions[2]
str
```

You can't free `str` as long as you're using the tokens. Either make a copy of the tokens, or keep `str` around.